# Error in Listview update always stops

Tags: android, listview

i have this listview update:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {     
display.elemek.clear();                     
em1.new AsyncEmBase().execute();

}
}, 0, 1000);
public class AsyncEmBase extends AsyncTask<Void, ListView, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // display.dataAdapter.clear();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

readInputRegisters();  /*this only makes display.elemek.add("SomeString")*/


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unsed) {
            if (display.dataAdapter == null) {
            display.dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    display.activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    display.elemek);

            display.lv.setAdapter(display.dataAdapter);
        } else {
            display.dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        }

    }
```

it runs smootly but after a while it stops and says:

```
11-27 15:21:05.769: E/AndroidRuntime(17991): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131296261, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
```

i have tried everithing to update the listview but nothing is good.
Please help me!

edit1: new error: Invalid index 7, size is 0
But i clear the elemek arraylist before starting to insert the datas

display.java:

```
public class display extends Fragment {

    public static TextView ain1, ain2, ain3, ain4, dout1, dout2, din1, din2,
            din3, din4, cin1, cin2, cin3, cin4, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8;
    public static Activity activity;
    public static ListView lv;
    public static ArrayList<String> elemek;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display, container, false);



        ain1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        activity = getActivity();

        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);      
        elemek = new ArrayList<String>();

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

`display.activity.runOnUiThread(...)` is useless because `onPostExecute()` is already executed inside the UI thread

and I don't think you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` because you're setting the adapter just before.

Comment: yes but witouth them is the same... or: Invalid index 8, size is 0; but i clear all the time the arraylist

Comment: Don't clear the data, you will have nothing to show then. And put the adapter code please

Comment: if i dont clear the data then it always add the string under and under but i always need a new list

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your Thread because you dont need uiThread in onPostExecute() and add like this :

```
if ( display.dataAdapter == null) {
        display.dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                display.activity,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, display.elemek);

        display.lv.setAdapter(display.dataAdapter);
}else{
        display.dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: ia have added the display.java, and the edited onpostexecute as yours